# resultCode is always 0 and request is always -1, . Activity.onActivityResult();

Tags: android, onactivityresult, start-activity

I would like to add this to another list of questions about `resultCode == 0` and `requestCode == 0`.

Here is the synopsis:
`NoteActivity` calls `NoteSettingsActivity` using `startActivityForResult()`.

I have searched the web and when I pressed back button when `super.onBackPressed()`, the `resultCode == 0`. Well after further researching, it seems it returns this code whenever the back button is pressed, but after botching that `super.onBackPressed()` call and just simply `finish()` the application the `onActivityResult()`'s `resultCode` is still equals to 0. It goes the same with `requestCode`.

Also, I tried manipulating the manifest file, I have done so many changes just to get this work but nothings works for me.

Here is the snippet. Note that I have reverted back to my previous commit so I have lost my recent modifications, but please take a look on the code I have wrote before I notice that the `resultCode` is always equals to 0 (`ACTIVITY_CANCELED`)

```
@Override
public void onNoteSettingsActivityCalled(Note note)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteSettingsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(NoteExtrasKey.EXTRA_NOTE_ID, note.getNoteID());

    startActivityForResult(intent, NoteRequest.REQUEST_UPDATE_SETTINGS);
}
```

Here is when the activity detected back press:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{   
    Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG, "NoteSettingsActivity.onBackPressed() has been called.");

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(NoteExtrasKey.EXTRA_NOTE_REMINDENABLED , mRemindEnabled);
    intent.putExtra(NoteExtrasKey.EXTRA_NOTE_REMINDEVERY   , mDaysSelected);
    intent.putExtra(NoteExtrasKey.EXTRA_NOTE_REMINDON      , String.valueOf(mRemindDateTime));
    intent.putExtra(NoteExtrasKey.EXTRA_NOTE_ID            , mTargetNoteID);

    if(getParent() != null)
        getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    else
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Here's how NoteActivity received the resulting call.

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int result, int request, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(result, request, intent);

    Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG, "NoteActivity.onActivityResult() has been called.");
    Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG, "NoteActivity.onActivityResult() result = " + result + " request = " + request);

    if(result == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
        return;

    switch(request)
    {
        case NoteRequest.REQUEST_UPDATE_SETTINGS:

            if(intent == null) return;

            int noteID = intent.getIntExtra(NoteExtrasKey.EXTRA_NOTE_ID, -1);
            String remindOnString = intent.getStringExtra(NoteExtrasKey.EXTRA_NOTE_REMINDON);

            if(remindOnString != null && !remindOnString.equals(""))
                mRemindDateTime = Timestamp.valueOf(remindOnString);

            mHasSettingsEnabled = true;
            mRemindEnabled = intent.getBooleanExtra(NoteExtrasKey.EXTRA_NOTE_REMINDENABLED, false);
            mSelectedDays = intent.getIntegerArrayListExtra(NoteExtrasKey.EXTRA_NOTE_REMINDEVERY);

            if(noteID < 0)
            {
                Note note = mNoteDatabaseHelper.getNote(noteID);
                note.setRemindEnabled(mRemindEnabled);
                note.remindEvery(mSelectedDays);
                note.remindOn(mRemindDateTime);

                onNoteItemUpdated(note); 
            }

            Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG, "NoteActivity.onActivityResult() NoteRequest.REQUEST_UPDATE_SETTINGS called.");

            break;

        default:
            Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG, "NoteActivity.onActivityResult() : unknown request code = " + request);
            break;
    }
}
```

`resultCode` equals 0 and `requestCode` requals -1 when I ran this. I have checked the intent passed on this and it is not null.

Here are the questions very related to this question. None of them worked:

- [Android onActivityResult is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510280/android-onactivityresult-is-always-0)
- [How do I handle the back button when startActivityForResult is
  active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542107/how-do-i-handle-the-back-button-when-startactivityforresult-is-active)
- [setResult does not work when BACK button pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679250/setresult-does-not-work-when-back-button-pressed)
- [Android: startActivityForResult always gets a resultCode of 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926284/android-startactivityforresult-always-gets-a-resultcode-of-0)
- [Android Calendar: onActivityResult's resultCode is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615301/android-calendar-onactivityresults-resultcode-is-always-)
- [onActivityResult always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191785/onactivityresult-always-returns-0)
- [onActivityResult() is being called at an unexpected time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460250/onactivityresult-is-being-called-at-an-unexpected-time)
- [Android - startActivityForResult immediately triggering
  onActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910840/android-startactivityforresult-immediately-triggering-)
- [onActivityResult() called prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354955/onactivityresult-called-prematurely)
- [Activity result is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199404/activity-result-is-always-0)
- [Android: Gallery intent returning resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297361/android-gallery-intent-returning-resultcode-result-canceled)
  [Android on activity result always return 0 and null intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507043/android-on-activity-result-always-return-0-and-null-intent)

I am losing a lot of important hours working on my project just figuring out what makes the value for resultCode and requestCode lose the value I sent along the way.

Any help and guidance will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Any flags on that second Activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct signature is

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```

You have request and result mixed up.

Comment: I was just a bit tired. I could have noticed! Thank you very much! You saved my life.

Comment: I did not mix up the signature, but I kept checking resultCode and thought I was looking requestCode, hope it would help someone who comes to look for the answer later.

Answer (score 29):

In my case, I got the resultCode == 0 error because of two reasons.

Firstly, I copied the method from a fragment instead of from another activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```

A good way to prevent this from happening is to `@Override` your method so that you know you are overriding the default activity onActivityResult method signature.

Use the correct signature:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```

Secondly, I was doing this:

```
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.like_count), people.size());
    Log.e(TAG, people.size() +" people ");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
```

The super.onBackPressed() set the resultCode before it was actually set hence it resulted in the 0.

A simple fix cause it to work properly:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.like_count), people.size());
    Log.e(TAG, people.size() +" people ");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: It saves my so much time and tention..:)
 use `super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: I am not sure if IIRC, there was once a time I trusted the intellisense in previous version in Android Studio and by god I swear it highlighted the first param to be filled in as 'resultCode' and then followed by 'requestCode' so maybe that is why.

Comment: nice and clean answer +1

Answer (score 4):

The call to `super.onBackPressed()` is the one that will in the end set the result code and send it back to the calling activity. Replace that call with a call to `finish()` and you should get the result code that you are looking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: On the link I have posted, I did similar thing. That doesn't work.

Comment: Yep, confirmed, I have tried as suggested. It did not work as well. I will try to see if this is reproducible when I create a button and setResult from there.

Comment: Is the getParent() call really necessary here? If NoteActivity is the calling activity and NoteSettingsActivity is the called one, you can just call setResult() and not getParent().setResult() and then call finish() to terminate the NoteSettingsActivity. Have you tried that?

Comment: I personally always used `setResult()` and then `finish()` and it worked. Do not use `super.onBackPressed()`.

Comment: I have done it as well. I mentioned that was on previous commit. But that doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Was facing the same issue while doing uninstalling an application from the device. It got resolved by putting:
intentObject.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true); before you do startActivityForResult.

Answer (score 0):

For the comers from *The Android Big Nerd Ranch* Book, it's probably a typo in your code, make sure you're comparing correctly:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CHEAT) {
if (RESULT_OK == resultCode) {...} 
...
}
```

**Reminder:** `RESULT_OK` is always -1 and it's existence means `setResult()` was called from the child Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the party, but:
I had the sam problem, for me it did not work because I was calling `onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()` before setting the result.

Like this:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed() // <---- PROBLEM
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.putExtra("KEY", "VALUE"))
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    // AND here I tried with this calls without luck. -> requireActivity().finish() or super.onBackPressed()
}
```